# Unable to update the state in useState Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, sanity

This is my code. I'm using sanity for content management and developing react native app. Here the API call is returning correct value however setdata is not updating the state services. So when I try to access this which is here `<Text className="font-bold text-lg">{data.name}</Text>`   It gives error. Please help me solving this error. error log is mentioned below. I'm calling this component in another component like this `{request? :  }'
Main code.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Image, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect,useState } from 'react'
import { Octicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Pressable } from 'react-native';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import client from '../sanity';

const Jobcard = () => {
    //console.log(data);
    const [services,setdata]=useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>
    {
        fetchdata();
    },[services]);
    
    const fetchdata=async()=>
    {
        try {
            const query=`*[_type == "service"]
            {accepter{_ref},requester{_ref},datetime,name,location,workhour}`;
           const response= await client.fetch(query);
              console.log(response);
              setdata(response);
              console.log(services);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
       
    }
    const requestService=()=>{
        // service request code should come here
        console.log("setrvice requested");
    }
    const renderpage=({data})=>
    {
        

            <View>
                <Text className="font-bold text-lg">{data.name}</Text>  
                <Text className="font-bold">{data.location}</Text>
                <Text>Workling hours:{data.workhour}</Text>
                <View className="flex-row justify-center mt-3 space-x-6 items-center">
    
               
                <View className="bg-green-500 px-2 py-2 rounded-md">
    
                <Pressable className="" android_ripple={{color:"gray"}} onPress={requestService}>
                            <Text className="text-center text-white">Request Now</Text>
                </Pressable>
                </View>
                </View>
            </View>
            {/* image part */}
            <View>
                <Image source={{uri:data.url}} className="h-24 w-24 rounded-full "></Image>
            </View>
   
           
     
          
    }
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
    <FlatList  data={services}
    renderItem={renderpage}/>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default Jobcard

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

In the `useEffect` I'm calling the function `fetchdate()`. The API call is successful and it returns this

```
 LOG  [{"accepter": {"_ref": "r7D6aPT0NrdX0UJBnRdPKr"}, "datetime": "2023-06-17T17:13:00.000Z", "location": {"_type": "geopoint", "alt": -2, "lat": 10.2365, "lng": 123.36}, "name": "Plumber", "requester": {"_ref": "d0d7a210-ba7d-4ff4-8b48-ddd662ceb9d4"}, "workhour": "9-11"}, {"accepter": {"_ref": "wTURNjP62fuXRm3qPkJlYb"}, "datetime": "2023-06-20T17:14:00.000Z", "location": {"_type": "geopoint", "alt": -3, "lat": 56.325, "lng": 12.56}, "name": "Nurse", "requester": {"_ref": "d0d7a210-ba7d-4ff4-8b48-ddd662ceb9d4"}, "workhour": "17-22"}, {"accepter": {"_ref": "wTURNjP62fuXRm3qPkJlYb"}, "datetime": "2023-06-22T17:15:00.000Z", "location": {"_type": "geopoint", "alt": -3, "lat": 12, "lng": 46.35}, "name": "Mechanic", "requester": {"_ref": "xnDGSrek1dgx2qitI95DEZ"}, "workhour": "9-12"}]
```

However, `response` is not updating. When I try to access the name property , It gives this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I read some posts which suggested to use useEffect() which I'm already using.
Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm rendering this component in another . here's the code `{request? <PostJob></PostJob>:  <Jobcard  ></Jobcard>}`

Comment: React Lifecycle is render > useEffect > render. At the first render, services is empty array. So, you might be put empty array filter which prevent to render when the FlatList component receives empty array

Comment: I tried `useEffect ` to render when page loads, `useEffect(....,[])` like this . But error persists. I used similar logic in another page which is working fine.

Comment: How about check the console.log(data.name) in renderPage function? I think it will returns undefined at the first time.

Comment: Yes it is returning undefined .

Comment: useEffect doesn't work at the first time. There is an initial rendering and React render the app using empty array which is the defaultValue that you defined -> `const [services,setdata]=useState([]);`

Comment: During the initial rendering, renderpage method try to use the data.name but it receives empty value so it crashes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254183/discussion-between-manoj-bhat-and-kangseohyun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to import `FlatList` from `react-native` instead.
 here you are using another component from another package it is not the same thing:

```js
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
```

you still need to use `data?.example` instead of `data.example`.
also add a `return` statement in `renderpage` function just before `<view>...</view>`